# Sessions works fine in local mode, but not in server

Tags: php, session

I've just developped a project, which uses sessions, in PHP. It works fine in local mode, but when I upload to server, it doesn't works. Well, it works at 50%, because when I send it by POST, I can get the whole session correctly, but when I do header(); to my index.php, session 
just desapeared.

1. Sessions are enabled in my server.
2. All docs has session_start(); at the top of page.
3. When I do header(); I set die(); below.
4. Syntax is correct. Got no errors.

Does anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: Enable error_reporting

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any error, that's the problem. I do print_r($_SESSION); to my index.php, and when I get back there, just after send form params, the array is still empty, like no params were sent. I only can get params into login.php, if I do print_r(), I can get the session fine.

Comment: is session_start() called above header()?

Comment: @RaheelHasan Yes. When I send it by POST, session is set. But when I back to my index.php, session not exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think, problem is arising because of your mistake while moving files from local to server. If session does not worked in server, we can say that its server problem. But you said session is working. So please check your codings. If it works on localhost then it should work on server too.

**Try this:**
On a new server, PHP session was not working. This server have a cpanel installed before, i have uninstalled it, there is no proper way of uninstalling cpanel, so i just removed all related cron jobs and cpanel folders.

To fix the PHP session problem i checked session.save_path which was set to /tmp, on checking i found it is read only.

It may be due to securetmp service of cpanel disabled during uninstallation. I set path to

```
session.save_path = “/var/tmp”
```

in php.ini and restarted apache, session started working.

I have founded above in following link : http://blog.hostonnet.com/session-not-working-in-php

**Other posibilites:**
sessions either aren't enabled or aren't configured correctly in the php.ini file on your server.